# COM Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC on Excel Save File

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

This has been bothering me for some time. I am trying to export a report to an excel function in a program. Everytime when I export the report and it prompts me to name and save the file, it throws this error :

```
COM Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

I know this has been asked in many forums but those solutions aren't working at all for me. I tried restarting VS, run VS as admin, changing column rows numbers,etc. No luck at all. The thing is, I have 10 different functions in the program and like 4-5 of them allowed me to save and export to excel successfully but the others functions throw this error.

This is part of the code that throws this error :

```
private void ExportExcel(SqlDataReader dr) {
  try {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Microsoft Office Excel Workbook (*.xls)|*.xls|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      // Create an Excel object and add workbook...
      Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
      Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true); // true for object template???

      // Add column headings...
      int iCol = 0;
      int iVisibleColumnCount = 0;
      foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns) {
        iCol++;
        // counting visible columns
        if (c.ColumnMapping != MappingType.Hidden)
          iVisibleColumnCount++;
        else    // hide the columns in excel is the column is hide in datatable
        {
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.Hidden = true;
          continue;
        }
          // Set column header text to bold
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).Font.Bold = true;
        excel.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;

        if (c.DataType == typeof(System.String))
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
        else if (c.DataType == typeof(System.Int16)
            || c.DataType == typeof(System.Int32)
            || c.DataType == typeof(System.Int64))
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0";
        else if (c.DataType == typeof(System.TimeSpan))
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = @"[$-409]hh:mm:ss AM/PM;@";
        else if (c.DataType == typeof(System.DateTime))
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
        else if (c.DataType == typeof(System.Decimal))
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = @"#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)";
        else
          ((Excel.Range) excel.Cells[1, iCol]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General";
      }
      // for each row of data...
      int iRow = 0;
      foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) {
        iRow++;

        // add each row's cell data...
        iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns) {
          iCol++;
          if (c.ColumnMapping != MappingType.Hidden) {
            Exception thrown at this line: excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
          }
        }
      }

      //                  // Global missing reference for objects we are not defining...
      //                  object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

      // If wanting to Save the workbook...
      workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
      //                  workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName,
      //                      Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, missing, missing,
      //                      false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
      //                      missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

      // If wanting to make Excel visible and activate the worksheet...
      //excel.Visible = !bCloseAfterExport;
      Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) excel.ActiveSheet;
      ((Excel._Worksheet) xlWorkSheet).Activate();

      workbook.Save();
      //save the workbook

      //if (bCloseAfterExport)
      workbook.Close(false, String.Empty, false);
      //close the workbook

      // End

      // If wanting excel to shutdown...
      //if (bCloseAfterExport)
      ((Excel._Application) excel).Quit();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Error message:

[image: Picture]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At which point it happens exactly? where is the line 2268?

Comment: Exception thrown at this line: excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];

Answer (score 1):

I believe my issue was some of my data (cell values) started with "=" and that caused the assignment to fail. Difficult to see when you're doing 000s of rows at once. Put the transfer in a loop and transfer 10 rows at a time (in a try catch block too so it can carry on).

Answer (score 0):

`excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol]` is a range. It has a Range type. you cannot set values like this. To set a value for a Range, you need to set its value or formula:

```
excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol].Value = r[c.ColumnName];
```